# Prevent Dart tests from logging every second

Tags: dart, testing

I'd prefer that Dart not log the current test description every second the test is under execution. If some test takes 5 seconds, Dart is logging the test description 5 times.

I would prefer the logging only represent the one time the test is attempted to be executed.

This is such strange default behavior when compared to other test suites, but I can't find anyone talking about the problem or offering solutions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apologies for answering my own question. Reporters (not logging) is the key search term.

There are four reporters available in the default Dart test package. You set the reporter by adding the --reporter <reporter_name> flag on the test command line.

https://github.com/dart-lang/test#selecting-a-test-reporter

The default is "compact" which logs continuously. The one I want to use is called "expanded".

Comment: What you will find with `expanded` is that it is the same as the default `compact`, except that it prints each update on a new line rather than overwrite the line in place. In other words, if you have a test that runs for some time, you will still see multiple updates for that one test using `expanded`. It's for this reason I ended up settling on the `github` reporter, because it is in fact just one line per test., although the formatting isn't ideal.